# Android Textwatcher gets called without typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

I have a TextWatcher added to some of my EditTexts. The problem is that the afterTextChanged gets called just by scrolling.

So if the EditText is currently not visible and i scroll up or down to the EditText the TextWatcher gets called.

How can i stop the TextWatcher from getting called by just "showing" the EditText?

Comment: codes + screenshot please. please.